# what does $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ means without the f ( $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I was reading in calculus 3 book , but I am stuck here

I don't understand what $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ means (I know it is partial derivative but I don't know what it means without f like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ )
and I don't understand how does  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}*Q=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ and what does $\nabla $ means without any function ?
It is like multiplying a number with a sign, which doesn't make any sense
I heard from 3b1b video that this is not only a notional trick but there is a relation between curl and cross product but I didn't understand what he means
it is in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB83DpBJQsE) at 11:00

[image]

Comment: @TeM but does it has a mathematical meaning ? if not then the curl is poorly defined which I don't think so

Comment: The formal definition of curl is the second line. The first line is a trick that help you to remember the formal definition

Comment: @TeM
i heard from 3b1b video that this is not only a notional tick but there is a relation between curl and cross product but I didn't understand what he means it is in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB83DpBJQsE at 11:00

Comment: It is merely the notation for an *operator*.  I trust you find nothing wrong with an elementary mathematics book saying "We will study for operations, +, -, *, and /."  A more advanced book might say "We will study two important operations, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\int$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is an operator, or an operation, which is a kind of function, that maps (differentiable multivariate) functions to other functions.

You're already familiar with other operators, for example "$+$" is an operator between pairs of numbers and numbers - we could just as easily write $+: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and use the notation $+(a, b)$, e.g. $+(3, 4) = 7$, but in practice we put the $+$ between the values instead.

So without a function being involved, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is just an operator floating around waiting to be applied to a function, and putting it to the left of a function is how we apply it, i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ (where on the left we have "differential operator being applied to a function", and on the right we have "derivative of a function").

In this form, we can manipulate it algebraically to some extent. For example, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is an operator, and it works so that if we apply it to a function $f$ it behaves in a sensible way, that is $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. We can even give it a name, so $\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

This isn't so different to being able to write $f$ on its own without asking "$f$ of what?". When you write $f + g$ you know that this represents "the function that applies $f$ and $g$ separately and then adds the results", which makes sense even when you don't write it explicitly as $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, and these operators take that abstraction one step further.

Expressing the curl as a matrix determinant is a little weirder, but it's mostly just taking advantage of the fact that the expression happens to look just like the $3 \times 3$ determinant. You *could* do full-on matrix algebra with operators, but you have to be careful with some things that are natural for numbers but not functions (For example, what's $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}$? Some kind of integral?)